# Android/Java simple FiFO buffer

Tags: java, android, buffer, fifo

I looking for simple byte FiFo buffer. I have to put and get or a single byte or array. But I can put every time single byte and get array and vice versa.
Any idea or example code to help me ?

Comment: See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/queue.html

Answer (score 8):

You can use a `LinkedList` as a queue:

```
    Queue<String> qe=new LinkedList<String>();

    qe.add("b");
    qe.add("a");
    qe.add("c");
    qe.add("e");
    qe.add("d");

    Iterator it=qe.iterator();

    System.out.println("Initial Size of Queue :"+qe.size());

    while(it.hasNext())
    {
        String iteratorValue=(String)it.next();
        System.out.println("Queue Next Value :"+iteratorValue);
    }

    // get value and does not remove element from queue
    System.out.println("Queue peek :"+qe.peek());

    // get first value and remove that object from queue
    System.out.println("Queue poll :"+qe.poll());

    System.out.println("Final Size of Queue :"+qe.size());
```

If you also want to add priorities you can use a `PriorityQueue`

If you need it to be thread safe use `ConcurrentLinkedQueue`

Also, as @Leonidos says, you can use a `ByteBuffer` is you need low level I/O, but be careful.

Feel free to comment on the post if you need any clarifications on how to use them.

Answer (score 2):

If you do intensive I/O you better adapt [ByteBuffer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html) for your needs. It works very fast and allows to write and read single byte data or byte array. ByteBuffer is tricky sometimes, be careful )